# A left rotation operation on an array of size n shifts

Tags: c#, arrays, rotation

I try to implement a left rotation on an array of size n shifts.
For example, I have

> array = {1,2,3,4,5};

and I have number of shifts:

> shifts = 2;

After processing the array it has to look like this:

> array = {3,4,5,1,2};

I have implemented it with two **for** loops:

```
var array = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5};
var shifts =3;
var temp = 0;
for(var j = 0; j < shifts; j++){
     temp = array[0];
     for(var i = 0; i < array.Length -1; i++){
         array[i] = array[i + 1];
     }
     array[array.Length-1] = temp;
}
for(var i =0 ; i< array.Length; i++){
    System.Console.Write(array[i]+ " ");
}
 Console.Read();
```

And it is working, but it isn't passing some tests with big amount of numbers in array and I get **Terminated due to timeout** error;

Are there any ways to implements left rotation in one loop?

Comment: Thirty seconds of googling later: [this](https://blog.geralexgr.com/csharp-dotnet/array-left-rotation-by-d-c-code)

Comment: If it is acceptable to generate a new array, then Patrick's solution would be quicker for large arrays. If you need to perform an in place shift, then you could use a combination of that solution to extract the first "shift" elements into a temporary array, then loop through the array in a single loop moving elements by "shift", then insert the temporary values at the end.

Comment: @PaulF, and if it's acceptable to operate further with `IEnumerable<T>` then one can avoid a new array by excluding `.ToArray()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this as efficient as you'll get for rotating an array in-place. Works for both left and right rotations, depending on the sign of `rotateBy`:

```
private static void Rotate<T>(T[] array, int rotateBy)
{
    rotateBy %= array.Length;
    // Nothing to do?
    if (rotateBy == 0)
        return;
    // Normalize it to a right rotation
    if (rotateBy < 0)
        rotateBy = array.Length + rotateBy;
    // Allocate the smallest possible temp array
    if (rotateBy > array.Length / 2)
    {
        T[] temp = new T[array.Length - rotateBy];
        Array.Copy(array, 0, temp, 0, array.Length - rotateBy);
        Array.Copy(array, array.Length - rotateBy, array, 0, rotateBy);
        Array.Copy(temp, 0, array, rotateBy, array.Length - rotateBy);
    }
    else
    {
        T[] temp = new T[rotateBy];
        Array.Copy(array, array.Length - rotateBy, temp, 0, rotateBy);
        Array.Copy(array, 0, array, rotateBy, array.Length - rotateBy);
        Array.Copy(temp, 0, array, 0, rotateBy);  
    }
}
```

Comment: You could also check for rotateBy == 0 & exit immediately - saves copying the entire array to a temporary array & back again.

Comment: @PaulF thanks. Also made sure it allocates the smallest possible temp array.

Answer (score 2):

This is cheating, but a LINQ solution could be:

```
var array = Enumerable.Range(0, 100).ToArray();
var shiftBy = 2;
var shifted = array.Skip(shiftBy).Concat(array.Take(shiftBy)).ToArray();
```

If your task is simply 'viewing' the array in this transformed way, to avoid creating a new array, exclude the end `.ToArray()` and iterate over the `IEnumerable<int>` directly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, your solutions is awesome but i have to do this using loops.

Comment: @UladzimirKhadakouski if you have a particular requirement, such as "implement this using loops only", then that **needs** to be in your question. You can't let people waste time answering your question, and only later tell them that their answer is invalid because of some condition which you never stated!

Comment: @canton7 yeah man, I will do it at the next time, whatever I voted up for this answer and Patrick got reputation, so he didn't waste time actually

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work using a rotating buffer with the size of the amount of shifts.

```
static void ShiftLeft(int[] array, int shifts)
{
    int length = array.Length;
    int actualShifts = shifts % length;
    if (actualShifts == 0) return;
    int[] buffer = new int[actualShifts];
    Array.Copy(array, buffer, actualShifts);
    int indexAddition = actualShifts - (length % actualShifts);
    for (int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        int current = array[i];
        int bufferIndex = (i + indexAddition) % actualShifts;
        array[i] = buffer[bufferIndex];
        buffer[bufferIndex] = current;
    }
}
```

EDIT: As pointed out by @canton7, the circular buffer adds unnecessary complexity. Below should do, basically @canton7's answer, although @canton7 his answer is still more efficient due to the smaller buffer:

```
int length = array.Length;
int actualShifts = shifts % length;
if (actualShifts == 0) return;
int[] buffer = new int[actualShifts];
Array.Copy(array, buffer, actualShifts);
Array.Copy(array, actualShifts, array, 0, length - actualShifts);
Array.Copy(buffer, 0, array, length - actualShifts, actualShifts);
```

Comment: _"this can be done in a single loop, with the second running backwards"_ - this still appears to be two loops - the inner loop shifting by 1 at a time, so probably going to take just as long as the original solution.

Comment: @PaulF edited my answer to contain a single loop. The previous was terribly inefficient.

Comment: Have you tested this solution ? Try shifting a sequence of 1-10 by 2, or 3

Comment: Interesting - because I get 3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10, 2, 1 & 4,5,6,7,8,9,10, 3,1, 2 - see https://dotnetfiddle.net/jV0FJu

Comment: @PaulF fixed calculating the buffer index in my edit. Thanks for your sharpness.

Comment: This looks significantly more complex than just using a couple of calls to `Array.Copy`. Your whole loop can be replaced by `Array.Copy(array, actualShifts, array, 0, length - actualShifts); Array.Copy(buffer, 0, array, length - actualShifts, actualShifts);`

Comment: @canton7 You are absolutely right. Your answer contains those calls to Array.Copy and that makes your answer the efficiency winner.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
 public class ArrayRotation{
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.println("enter size of array:");
         int n=sc.nextInt();                                         
         int arr[]=new int[n];
         System.out.println("enter elements:");
         for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
         arr[i]=sc.nextInt();
         System.out.println("enter shifts:");
         int d=sc.nextInt();
         int arr1[]=new int[d];
         for(int i=0;i<d;i++)
         arr1[i]=arr[i];
        System.out.println("Array after rotating");
        for(int i=d;i<n;i++)
          System.out.print(arr[i]+" ");
        for(int i=0;i<d;i++)
         System.out.print(arr1[i]+" ");
}
```

}

Comment: why did you use java for c# solution ?